# What is the difference in this similar sentences?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

I came across this thinking:

1 - "the mayor of the city wants available house to homeless people"

2 - "the mayor of the city wants house available to homeless people"

do they have different meaning or is it just a situation where one is the correct writing?

in a similar train of thought i'd ask:

1 - house divided

2 - divided house

any difference?

Comment: Can you revisit your question because, at the moment, it is off-topic. The first part is asking "is this correct", which is off-topic (proofreading), and the second part doesn't really have a focus at all. Have you done any research?

Comment: I’m closing this question because it asks about the differences between two sentences, both of which are ungrammatical to such a degree that the original intent is not clear enough to correct them.

Answer (score 1):

Neither sentence makes sense. We would have to say

> The mayor of the city wants to make houses available to homeless people.

or

> The mayor of the city wants houses to be made available to homeless people.

We would normally speak of 'a divided house' unless we are saying 'a house [which is] divided into flats/apartments'. However, the expression *a house divided* is familiar to many people from the Bible verse Mark 3:25 "And if a house be divided against itself, that house cannot stand" (KJV). See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincoln%27s_House_Divided_Speech

Comment: When you say "make sense" you mean from grammar point of view right? I heard that in one of Netflix I watch. It ass subtitled just like: "the mayor of the city wants house available to homeless people" It may not be grammatical but it is Understandable right?

Comment: If the mayor was referring to one particular house, s/he would say _the house_ or _that house._ Maybe there was an error in the subtitling.

Comment: @EulleraValiente - bad English which is "understandable" is still bad English, and we don't encourage bad English here.

Comment: @Michael Harvey, that's fair enough